# Microsoft Access - How to perform validation check and produce error message

Tags: ms-access

I would like to produce an error message when the (sumofqtyreturn + sumofqtyissued) is greater than sumofqtyordered. I want to carry out this validation check so that when the user enters a value(qtyreturn or qtyissued) which is greater than the balance, the system should produce an error. Can this be done?

This is the sql view for my query:

```
SELECT i.itemNo, Nz(TotalOrdered,0), Nz(TotalReturned,0), Nz(TotalIssued,0), 
     (Nz(TotalOrdered,0)-Nz(TotalIssued,0)+Nz(TotalReturned,0)) AS Balance

FROM ((item AS i 

LEFT JOIN (SELECT itemno, Sum(qtyordered) AS TotalOrdered 

FROM delivered_item 

GROUP BY itemno)  AS d ON d.itemno=i.itemno)

LEFT JOIN (SELECT itemno, Sum(qtyreturn) AS TotalReturned FROM item_return 

GROUP BY itemno)  AS r ON r.itemno=i.itemno)

LEFT JOIN (SELECT itemno, Sum(qtyissued) AS TotalIssued FROM item_issued 

GROUP BY itemno)  AS iss ON iss.itemno=i.itemno
```

or any1 has other good idea of how to inform/warn the user something is wrong about the qtyissued/qtyreturn?(value too large)

Comment: Consider IIf as an Expression

Comment: @remou can you me with that, like giving me example? can error msg be produced based on the llf?

Comment: You are using sql, you can add an IIf statement to give a message, but not, sticktly speaking, an error message. If you need something fancy, you need to look at forms and VBA.

Comment: k sorry then, erm if it is a message, can you help me with the llf code, so that i can see what u mean.Thanks

Comment: @mike do you all how to solve this?hope u all still remember me.appreciate very much if can help

Comment: @parakmiakos do you all how to solve this?hope u all still remember me.appreciate very much if can help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the general idea.

```
SELECT q.AText, 
       q.SumOfANumber, 
       q.SumOfADecimal, 
       IIf([SumOfANumber]-[SumOfADecimal]<0,"Problem!","Yes") AS IsOkay
FROM (SELECT t.AText, 
            Sum(t.ANumber) AS SumOfANumber, 
            Sum(t.ADecimal) AS SumOfADecimal
      FROM Table1 As t
      GROUP BY t.AText)  AS q;
```

The aggregate query becomes a subquery and the relevant fields are compared in the main query. I have used aliases for Table1, so you have `Table1 As t`, and for the subquery.

Comment: can u attach me a picture for the outcome of your general idea?thanks